# Angular JS ng-repeat not displaying values

Tags: angularjs, html, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I am making an REST call from angular to Spring . I am able to get the response back .When i am trying to populate the values in the view using ng-repeat , nothing is shown on the screen .

This is my Angular Code This code is inside the showhidecontroller

```
  var resuls = $http.post('http://localhost:8080/aeservices/AddConfig', dataobj);
          resuls.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.dbresponse= data;
                $scope.messagetest = $scope.dbresponse[0].messages;
                alert($scope.messagetest);
                console.log( $scope.messagetest);
                console.log(data);

                });
```

This is my Response i recieved from API

```
    [{
"data12": null,
"name": null,
"errors": ["error data1", "error data2"],
"messages": ["Configuration has been Added successfully", "Configuration has been Added successfully"]
}]
```

This is my HTML

```
     <table ng-controller="ShowHideController">
<tr ng-repeat="item in dbresponse[0].errors" >
        <span><td align="left" class="validationMsg"><img src="images/red_bullet.gif" border="0" width="8" height="8" alt="">&nbsp
{{item}}
</td></span></tr>
</table>
```

I tried using ng-repeat by declaring myself an item like this               $scope.items = ['one','two','three','four']. Even this is not showing up on the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using data.data,

**Controller:**

```
app.controller("listController", ["$scope", "$http",
  function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('test.json').then(function(response) {
      $scope.dbresponse = response.data;
    });
  }
]);
```

**HTML:**

```
  <table ng-controller="listController">
      <tr ng-repeat="item in dbresponse[0].errors">
        <td align="left" class="validationMsg"><img src="images/red_bullet.gif" border="0" width="8" height="8" alt=""> {{item}}
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/pR8Gp6La4YdKFv92OnqD?p=preview)

Comment: How is this any different than what op has posted? (your edit makes more sense now)

Comment: @ForeignObject yes i was in the middle, hope its better now

Comment: Hey , you are doing the same thing i have done , May i know where i am going wrong

Comment: $scope.dbresponse = data.data;

Comment: I did the Same now as you suggested , but still its not coming up in the view

Comment: No errors sajeeth. Its not getting displayed on the view :( . I am able to see alert , console.log but its just not getting loaded in the view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129465/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-praveen).

Comment: come to the discussion chat

Answer (score 0):

Please try this below code and don't declare variable resuls.

```
  $http.post('http://localhost:8080/aeservices/AddConfig', dataobj).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.dbresponse= data;
                $scope.messagetest = $scope.dbresponse[0].messages;
                alert($scope.messagetest);
                console.log( $scope.messagetest);
                console.log(data);

                });
```

Comment: I tried this and able to get the Alert, but my problem is i am not able to display it on the html

Comment: As you are making AJAX call in an variable doesn't return anything.

Comment: I have chnaged my code and tried the way you have mentioned, but still its not working . I hope there might be a problem with my controller/html part

Comment: Before trying ng-repeat. Just try  $scope.test="preveen"; and display in html and let me know whether it displays praveen ?

Comment: No it is not getting displayed

Comment: Oh then. It might be some mistake in route config.

Comment: No there is no mistake  :(

Answer (score 0):

The Problem that happened was i have declared my controller twice in the HTML